# How to sort the table and re-generate it with help of pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table

I need to sort the table by name. For sorting, I use the function

```
function sortArray(index) {
  let arr = [];
  rows.forEach( elem => {
    arr.push(elem.children[index].textContent); 
  })
  let sort = arr.sort( (a, b) => {
    if ( a > b) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  console.log(sort);
  return sort;
  }
```

but I don't know how to redraw the table. Table I create from JSON file dynamically. In order to start sorting, you need to click on the name of the field and then the already sorted table should be displayed.

```
const buildHeader = data =>
  Object.keys(data)
    .map(k => `<th>${k}</th>`)
    .join("");
const buildRow = data =>
  Object.keys(data)
    .map(k => `<td>${data[k]}</td>`)
    .join("");
let element = document.querySelector(".people");

function showPeople(people) {
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("people__table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  thead.innerHTML = `<tr class="head">${buildHeader(people[0])}</tr>`;
  table.appendChild(thead);
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  tbody.innerHTML = people
    .map(p => `<tr class="person">${buildRow(p)}</tr>`)
    .join("");
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  element.appendChild(table);
}

const customPeople = data =>
  data.map((p, i) => {
    return {
      name: p.name,
      sex: p.sex,
      born: p.born,
      died: p.died,
      age: p.died - p.born,
      mother: p.mother,
      father: p.father,
    };
  });

showPeople(customPeople(ANCESTRY_FILE));
```

Comment: If you create the table dynamically from JSON to begin with, can you not repeat this process with the sorted data?

Comment: aside: this approach works, but innerHTML isn't really necessary. The HTMLTableElement comes equipped with table creation methods like `createTHead` `insertRow`, etc. Likewise HTMLTableRow contains methods like `insertCell`, `deleteCell`, etc.

Comment: @Lewis It is, of course, possible, but how to make these data sorted with clicks on the field names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this `sortTable` function would do the job:

```js
function sortTable(tbody, index, ascending) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(tbody.children).sort(
        (tr1, tr2) => tr1.children[index].textContent.localeCompare(tr2.children[index].textContent) * (ascending ? 1 : -1)
        ).forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr));
    }

// demonstration
(function(){
    const thead_tr = document.getElementById('thdtr');
    const tbody = document.getElementById('tbd');
        
    function makeCell() {
        const td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Math.round(Math.random() * 999999999).toString(36)));
        return td;
        }

    function makeRow() {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for(let i = 0; i < thead_tr.children.length; i++) tr.appendChild(makeCell());
        return tr;
        }
    
    // adds click-to-sort functionality
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(thead_tr.children, (th, index) => {
        let asc_toggle = false; // false will start off in ascending order
        th.addEventListener('click', event => sortTable(tbody, index, asc_toggle = !asc_toggle));
        });
    
    // fills the table with random alphanumeric data
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) tbody.appendChild(makeRow());
    }());
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="thdtr">
            <th>col 1</th>
            <th>col 2</th>
            <th>col 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbd">
    </tbody>
<table>
```

My `sortTable` function is a generic in-place table sorting function that should work on any table. It accepts 3 parameters:

1. `tbody` - `DOMElement` - A reference to either the `tbody` element or the `table` element itself, whichever contains the `tr` (row) elements.
2. `index` - `Number` - The index of the column to sort by (starts at `0`).
3. `ascending` - `Boolean` - Whether the order is ascending (`true`) or descending (`false`)

Example usage for use with your current code:

`sortTable(document.querySelector('.people__table tbody'), 0, true);`

Answer (score 0):

You could reappend the rows to the tables body:

```
 const body = document querySelector(".people__table > tbody");

 for(const el of sort)
   body.appendChild(el);
```

Or you just sort the data and regenerate the whole table.

Comment: It is, of course, possible, but how to make these data sorted with clicks on the field names. By using the way of sorting started JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the example below:

```js
let data = generateData();

let columns = [
  {
    name: "id",
    callback: function() {
      flags.id *= -1;
      doSortInt("id", flags.id);
    }
  },
  {
    name: "name",
    callback: function() {
      flags.name *= -1;
      doSortStrings("name", flags.name);
    }
  },
  {
    name: "age",
    callback: function() {
      flags.age *= -1;
      doSortInt("age", flags.age);
    }
  }
];

var flags = {
  id: -1,
  name: -1,
  age: -1
};

createBasicTable(columns);

populateDataToTable(data);

function doSortInt(prop, flag) {
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return flag * (b[prop] - a[prop]);
  });
  populateDataToTable(data);
}

function doSortStrings(prop, flag) {
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return flag * ("" + a[prop]).localeCompare(b[prop]);
  });
  populateDataToTable(data);
}

/**
 * This function is used to fill in the table with data from array
 */
function populateDataToTable(data) {
  let tableBody = document.querySelector("#table-body");
  // remove all childs
  while (tableBody.firstChild) {
    tableBody.removeChild(tableBody.firstChild);
  }

  // add new data
  data.forEach(function(el) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");

    let th1 = document.createElement("th");
    th1.innerHTML = el.id;
    tr.appendChild(th1);

    let th2 = document.createElement("th");
    th2.innerHTML = el.name;
    tr.appendChild(th2);

    let th3 = document.createElement("th");
    th3.innerHTML = el.age;
    tr.appendChild(th3);

    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

/**
 * This function is used to create a basic empty table
 */
function createBasicTable(columns) {
  let element = document.querySelector("#table-container");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("people__table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");

  let tr = document.createElement("tr");

  columns.forEach(function(col) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    th.classList.add("head");
    th.innerHTML = col.name;
    th.addEventListener("click", col.callback);
    // add listener here
    tr.appendChild(th);
  });
  thead.appendChild(tr);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  tbody.id = "table-body";
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  element.appendChild(table);
}

/**
 * This function is used to generate some data for the table
 */
function generateData() {
  let data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let obj = {
      id: i,
      name: "Name_" + (i + 1),
      age: 30 + i * 2
    };
    data.push(obj);
  }

  return data;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="table-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main points are:

In column definitions array you have callbacks for each column header. Then you call the function

```
createBasicTable
```

which creates an empty table without data. And in this function you registers the column headers callbacks. Then you have a function

```
populateDataToTable
```

which takes an array as a parameter and uses this array to build table rows.
Finally, in your callbacks, you just need to sort your data array properly and update the table content with function:

```
populateDataToTable
```

p.s. Code is not prefect, but it should at least give you a hint, how to implement this functionality.
I will try to improve the code tomorrow.

Comment: If you look at my answer you should be able to see that the solution to this issue isn't at all very complex, nor does it require a complete overhaul of the algorithm used to generate the table.